# Where to define local temp variables in Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, scope

I took too long to use warnings; and strict; in Perl, but now I did, I see the advantages.

One of the things I'm still not sure about is when to define a temporary variable. This may seem like a trivial thing, but I run a lot of Monte Carlo simulations where losing a bit of time adds up over 10000+ iterations. I've been lazy about using strict/warnings on quicker simulations, but they've gotten more complex, so I really need to.

So (cutting out code to calculate stuff) I am wondering if

```
sub doStuff
{
  my $temp;
  for my $x (1..50)
  {
    $temp = $x**2;
  }
  for my $x (1..50)
  {
    $temp = $x**3;
  }
}
```

Or

```
sub doStuff
{
  for my $x (1..50)
  {
    my $temp = $x**2;
  }
  for my $x (1..50)
  {
    my $temp = $x**3;
  }
}
```

Is less/more efficient, or if one violates some Perl coding I didn't know yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The efficiency between these two is close enough, and it is dwarfed by any realistic processing. So I'd go by code – if the `$tmp` is indeed temporary and unneeded after the loop then it is better to keep it inside (scoped), for all the other reasons.

Since this is about optimization I'd like to digress. Such micro-issues may have an effect. However, where you really gain is first at the level of algorithms, and then by choosing data structures and techniques suitably. The low-level tweaks are the very last thing to think about, and there are often language features and libraries that render them irrelevant. That said, one should know one's tool and not waste time around.

Also, there is often a trade-off between the code clarity and efficiency. If it comes to that I suggest to code for correctness and clarity. Then profile and optimize if needed, cautiously and gradually, and with a lot of testing in between.

Here is a comparison, as an example of basic use of the core module [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). I throw in an additional operation and add other cases where there is no temporary.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;    
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $x;

sub tmp_in {
    for (1..10_000) {
        my $tmp = 2 * $_;
        $x = $tmp + $_;
    }
    return $x;
}

sub tmp_out {
    my $tmp;
    for (1..10_000) {
        $tmp = 2 * $_;
        $x = $tmp + $_;
    }
    return $x;
}

sub no_tmp {
    for (1..10_000) { $x = 2 * $_ + $_ }
    return $x;
}

sub base {
    for (1..10_000) { $x += $_ }
    return $x;
}

sub calc { 
    for (1..10_000) { $x += sin sqrt(rand()) }
    return $x;
}         

cmpthese(-10, {
    tmp_in  => sub { tmp_in  },
    tmp_out => sub { tmp_out },
    no_tmp  => sub { no_tmp  },
    base    => sub { base    },        
    calc    => sub { calc    },
});
```

Output (on v5.16)

```
          Rate    calc  tmp_in tmp_out  no_tmp    base
calc     623/s      --    -11%    -26%    -44%    -59%
tmp_in   698/s     12%      --    -17%    -37%    -54%
tmp_out  838/s     34%     20%      --    -25%    -44%
no_tmp  1117/s     79%     60%     33%      --    -26%
base    1510/s    142%    116%     80%     35%      --
```

So they differ, and apparently a declaration in a loop costs. But `tmp` versions are together in the list. Also, this is often just overhead so it is greatly exaggerated. And there are other aspects – `no_tmp` runs in one statement, for example. These things may matter only if your processing is mostly iterations.  Just generating a (high quality) pseudo-random number is expensive.

This may also differ (wildly) across different hardware and software versions. My results with v5.10 on a better machine are a bit different. Replace the sample 'calculations' with your processing, and run on the actual hardware, for a relevant measure of whether it matters at all.

Comment: Just for completeness: I tried your code and added a modified version of `no_tmp()` which also does a multiplication (like the others do), i.e. instead of your `$x += $_;` I did `$x = 2*$_ + $_;` so that all subroutines give the same result. Due to the multiplication my `no_tmp_mod()` is slower than yours and closer to `tmp_out()`. [See hastebin](http://hastebin.com/hubewisehi.pl). But as you already said: the real difference will come from the actual calculation, not from _in_ vs. _out_.

Comment: @PerlDog  Yes, that is different, thank you for the comment.  I meant to add a 'reference' sub which isn't the same, but I should include more, you are right.  Also, there are issues with `$tmp` getting optimized away, etc.  This was meant to be a basic sample for the OP, and a simple demo.  I plan on improving as I get a little time.  Thank you

Comment: @PerlDog  Finally got around to it and updated as planned. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @aschultz I added a bit more to the benchmark example, with more specific commentary (and edited a little elsewhere)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would keep the temporary variable in the for loop. Just because that is where it is used. The other way, at some point down the line it will come back to bite you (or the person who has to pick up your code) with an unexpected value.

Also [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

> Optimization can reduce readability and add code that is used only to
>      improve the performance. This may complicate programs or systems, 
>      making them harder to maintain and debug. As a result, optimization 
>      or performance tuning is often performed at the end of the development 
>      stage.

Comment: While a straight up "thanks" is not what comments are for, I want to say--thanks for the explanation as well as giving me a sense of relief about when I've optimized my own projects. Often when I find optimizations I say "why didn't I see that earlier" but it's good to know that its's not what I should be looking for, except in cases of extreme slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
for my $x ( 1 .. 50 ){
   my $temp = $x**2;
}# $temp goes out of scope
```

$temp will be out of scope after the for loop.
That basically means it no longer exists.

If you do:

```
my $temp;
for my $x ( 1 .. 50 ){

   $temp = $x**2;

}# $temp is now 50**2;
```

$temp will be in the subroutine scope,
and can be altered or returned later in the sub.

Take a look at [variable scoping in perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677) to find out more.

I agree with above poster that you should keep your variables in the scope where they are used. That way it is much clearer for you, and other people reading your code later, what the variable is for, and you will not get bugs related to assuming it was empty when it was still holding a previous value.

If you need more speed, consider upgrading perl - for example, perl 5.24 has some nice performance increases which will far outweigh some variable saved.

You should only optimize after the code works, and only where it actually helps, which you can find out by benchmarking (for example using [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.24.0/lib/Benchmark.pm)).